# Find deeply nested (descendants) element (id) in angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, find, element

I've been sitting with this all day now: In my Directive in AngularJS I can not find a nested element with a certain id. jQuery is loaded and used.

The HTML:

```
<div class="container_header-login">
    <div class="shit" data-ng-if="!login">
        <input type="text" placeholder="username/email"/>
        <input type="text" placeholder="password"/>
        <br/>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
        <a href="#">Register</a>            
        <a href="#">Forgot password</a> 
        <p id="test">shit</p>
    </div>

    <div data-ng-if="login">

    </div>
</div>
```

The Directive:

```
var mHeaderLogin = angular.module('app.directives.mHeaderLogin', ['mMain'])// mMain-dependent due to factory call
.directive('dHeaderLogin', fHeaderLogin);
function fHeaderLogin() {
    console.log("login");
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        //replace: true,
        scope: {}, //isolate scope
        templateUrl: 'app/directives/header-Login/header-Login.html',
        controller: function ($scope, simpleFactory) {
            $scope.users = simpleFactory.getUsers();
            $scope.bLogin = false;
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.find("#test").bind('click', function () {
                alert("clicked");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The only thing that has worked is to use (the asterisk):

```
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.find("*").bind('click', function () {
            alert("clicked");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using jquery instead of [ng-click](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick)?

Comment: Directly get the id of the element as $("#test').bind('click',function(){ });

Comment: Jax: answer is basically "i don't know". I'm new to Angular. I'm not sure yet when ng-click is appropriate and when to watch elements. Anyhow, I still need to better understand the angular.element and how to work with it. Anil: it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of the elements with `data-ng-if` have been rendered at the point when the link function is called.

You need to let Angular finalize the digestion by adding a call to `$timeout()`:

```
$timeout(function () {
  element.find("#test").bind('click', function() {
    alert("clicked");
  });
});
```

Another issue that you had already covered but other readers might miss is that you need to load jQuery before Angular. Otherwise Angular will use jqLite, and for `find()`this means (see [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)):

> `find()` - Limited to lookups by tag name

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/masa671/f3k55zms/

Comment: It works! Thank you! I will have to look into $timeout - great! Perhaps should mention also that $timeout need to be added as argument in directive function (fHeaderLogin) as is done in the fiddle